# merge rows in excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, merge

I have a lot of rows with different values, but in the first column I have the same value. My goal is to merge the different lines into one based on the value of the first column. In the example, only one name should remain that has all values ​​in one line

[image: Example]

Comment: Good question, but please rephrase so it is more understandable. Try and show a before and after of what you intend, and use correct punctuation and grammar (don't forget commas!). Then it would be a more answerable question.

Comment: Can a column have multiple entries for a given name? i.e. Could there be a `1` in `B2` and `B4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my result for the data you show.

I used Excel's "Subtotal" function. 
You may still be able to access it by its old keyboard shortcut,
<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>. 
In Excel 2013 it is <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>,
or you can click the "Subtotal" button
in the "Outline" panel on the "Data" tab. 
If you can't find it, try the search bar in the header.

1. Select all your values including the heading. 
   Do not include anything extra. 
   You can also begin with cursor in `A1`
   provided all your latest data and modifications are saved.
2. Subtotal window will include these options:

   - At each change in: **Name**
   - Use function: **Sum**
   - Add subtotal to: **<check all Value columns>**
   - Leave the boxes checked for **Replace current subtotals**
     and **Summary below data**
3. Click on OK and the results will calculate. 
   You now see a sheet with 1, 2 and 3 to the left of your data. 
   Clicking on the **2** will show you only the totals, like the picture below. 
   (**1** will show only the grand totals;
   **3** will go back to showing all the data.)

   [image: resulting spreadsheet]

Comment: Thank you very much :)